# Some image URLs don't work in webClient downloadData method in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell why some URLs as below table are fail to download? But some URLs are OK with same hosting.

```
URLs
http://hositing/mylibrary/image.jpd.png
http://hositing/mylibrary/a_asd.png
http://hositing/mylibrary/a?asd.png
//is it because of the special characters?
```

If it is because of the special characters, is there a way to solve it? The URL is entered by client, so there is a case to destroy my program.

If it is no way to solve it, i will disable the process if the URL contains any special character.

some code for reference:

```
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(@"http://hositing/mylibrary/image.jpd.png");
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
  Image myImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: We would need the actual urls entered, or at least the exception details of the failure.

Comment: @SimonSvensson The error message is about "unhandled  Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: <401> Unauthorized. at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal<Uri address, WebRequest& request>"

Comment: The exception tell clear what is the proplem.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Equivalent to HTTP status 401. Unauthorized indicates that the requested resource requires authentication. The WWW-Authenticate header contains the details of how to perform the authentication.

Comment: OH! It is a permission problem.i will open another post for that. Can anyone close this post?